# Transfer WordPress Plugin to a new site?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, ftp

how is the procedure to transfer one plugin to site A to B with the plugin data included? I am able to transfer the FTP data for sure but I need the saved files of the plugin also. So I need to do some actions in the database.

Where do I find the plugins database, where to extract and import it? Did not find it in wpoptions.

Bests,

Download FTP data and extract it in new site.

Comment: Every plugin are different... you should take notes about: does your plugin insert data in database and in wich tables? Does your plugin save files, where?  It's difficult to answer without knowing at least the plugin name.

Comment: Hi! The plugin is called WP Customer Reviews, https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/ Anyone who can help?

Comment: Ask the plugin developer how to export and then import its data. That's the first place to go with questions about plugins, especially data-intensive ones.

Comment: Hi,

I did that weeks ago. I am getting no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins have an import/export feature - Worth looking around settings if you haven't already.

Comment: Sadly it does not. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Looking the plugin code it seems that they insert reviews into posts table. So, in order to import them, you should use a post export/import system.

It saves in postmeta the ratings with type columns setted to `wpcr3_review_rating` and posts for comments with type `wpcr3_review`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the hint. Could you give me a bit more precise step by step tutorial on this?

Comment: Really looking forward to your help!

Comment: @Digimy i'm so sorry but this is not how StackOverflow works. Anyway did you tried this? [LINK](https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-import-export-woocommerce-product-reviews/)

Comment: There's also a youtube video for the import https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSjWDN6PZoc